# How to set random seed in tensorflow

Tags: python, random, tensor, seed

Can someone please tell how to set a random seed in tensor flow?
Like in numpy:

```
np.random.seed(seed = some_number)
```

I have tried:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
tf.set_random_seed(seed = 42)
```

but it does not seem to work.
Thank you!

Comment: if you use always the same number then you always get the same values. Maybe use something more random - like current timestamp as `seed`

Comment: the problem is, that I don't get the same values, code I used (with sess.Session() etc.) doesn't work

Comment: it can means it uses random seed and it doesn't care for your settings. And it would need digging in source code to change it.

Answer (score 1):

To set the global random seed:

```
tf.random.set_seed(seed)
```

Where the argument `seed` is your `some_number`

From https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed

Comment: I've tried this code too and received an error:
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'random'

Comment: Which version of Tensorflow do you have installed? I've successfully run the code with tensorflow version 2.0.